# Alternative Windows program for editing Excel xml format spreadsheets

Tags: windows, xml, microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I don't have Microsoft Office at home, but would occasionally like to edit spreadsheets from work. We use the Excel .xml format also knows as ["SpreadsheetML"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpreadsheetML).

Does anybody know of a program that will do that for Windows 10?

More specifically the format details are at the top of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
```

It appears [Gnumeric](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnumeric/stable/sect-file-formats.html.en) supports the format, but it does not exist for Windows.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

XML is the Extensible Markup Language. Are you sure you're not referring to .xls or .xlm files?

The best option IMHO is [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/). LibreOffice Calc uses the ODS format by default, but it can read and write many others. Plus, it's free and open source.

Comment: Yes, I refer to spreadsheets saved in .xml format from Excel (not .xls or .xlm). I will try LibreOffice.

Comment: Tried, but it appears to just interpret it as plain text or csv for import purposes. I will keep it installed though to edit stuff from my linux machine.